# regex to match until a colon is found with or without quotes present

Tags: regex, pcre

I'm looking for a regex to achieve the following:

When my input is  `root:Folder1:fname` I want to get `fname`

and when the input string is `root:Folder1:'fname'` to get again `fname` *(no quotes!)*.

For the former `[^:?]*$` seems to get the job done but I cannot find a single regex to match both cases.

Is it possible to do it with a single regex? Tried to achieve it with conditional regex but I couldn't make it.

Any other tip/solution is welcome.

Thank you.

edit: The format of the paths is not fixed, quotes might appear elsewhere (e.g. root:'Folder with spaces1':fname or root:'Folder with spaces1':'fname'). The solution I guess is to search backwards as the filename we want to capture is *always* after the *last* colon.

Comment: You meant to write `root:Folder1:'fname'` instead of `root:Folder1:'name'`?

Comment: @TJ yes. I edited the post.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to enforce paired quotes, you need to capture the first quote.

```
(\w+:)*('?)(\w+)\2$
```

The expression inside the third pair of parentheses will be available as the third captured group (`$3` or `\3` or `match.group(3)` or what have you).

If your regex dialect permits non-grouping parentheses, you can rearticulate this as

```
(?:\w+:)*('?)(\w+)\1$
```

and/or also perhaps extend the quote group to permit either single or double quote (`['"]?`pro `'?`).  Then of course the final group will be `$2` instead of `$3`.

Comment: Going forward, please review the guidance in [the Stack Overflow `regex` tag info page](/tags/regex/info); you basically always need to specify which particular regex tool or dialect you need a solution for. That also reduces the amount of hedge words and speculation in answers.

Comment: The solution works in most cases but fails when the filename has spaces. I changed it to (\w+:)*('?)(\w+[^:?]+)\2$ and now seems to catch every case.

Comment: Just say `[^:]` instead of `\w` if that's what you mean. Strictly speaking I guess my `\w` should be `[^\W:]`

Answer (score 1):

As you tagged pcre, you might also use a branch reset group to get group 1 between single quotes or not between single quotes.

```
^.*:(?|'(\w+)'|(\w+))$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `.*:` Match until the last `:`
- `(?|` Branch reset group

  - `'(\w+)'` Capture 1+ word chars between single quotes
    `|` Or
    `(\w+)` Capture 1+ word chars
- `)` Close branch reset group
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LTdj3s/1)

Comment: I think it's the only good answer but remove `^.*` that is useless and counter-performing.

Answer (score 0):

This will work if your "grammar" is strict:

`(\w+:)*'?(\w+)'?`

- First we repeat anyword: from 0 to infinite times
- then we consume a single quote if it exists
- then we record the last word
- then we consume the last quote if it exists

Watch the regex debugger here:
https://regex101.com/r/SjoWYP/1

Comment: Dear @DoLooP, the format is not strict. We could have something like: root:Folder1:'Folder with literal name 1':'fname'. We are definitely sure that we want to capture the part after the last colon, which is the name of the file we want. So it might be better to search backwards? I changed your suggestion to (^:?)*'?(\w+)'?$  (https://regex101.com/r/I5otrx/1). It gets the fname and 'fname' now. But the result we want is to get in both cases fname as result.

Comment: You a want a single result, not a subgroup i get it. You should use a lookbehind first group then. Hoping it is compatible with your regex flavor. I'll edit my answer asap.